# Automatically triggering an action in Ember when clicking on elements with a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I automatically trigger an action whenever an element containing a specific attribute in an Ember 3.11 project is clicked?

Currently, my structure is as follows:

```
myComponent.js:

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  @action
  elementClicked(someValue) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

```
myTemplate.hbs:

<div onclick={{action 'elementClicked' 'someValue'}}>
  some text
</div>
```

What I want is to achieve the following:

```
myTemplate.hbs:

<div trackClick='somevalue'>
  some text
</div>
```

Whenever an element has the 'trackClick' attribute defined in any template, I want the 'elementClicked' method that I've defined to be executed. I don't want to manually add this to each component separately.

Instead of defining the action separately for each component, I would like to define it globally in a single location. My intention is to trigger this globally defined action whenever any element within any component, which has the 'trackClick' attribute, is clicked.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<div trackClick='somevalue'>
  some text
</div>
```

You want to use the `on` modifier to call a function:

```
<div {{on 'click' elementClicked}} data-track="somevalue">
  some text
</div>
```

and then in your component:

```
@action
elementClicked(clickEvent) {
  let value = clickEvent.target.getAttribute('data-track');
}
```

Docs here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/

---

Per request, a global event listening, using eventDelegation, you'll want to do something similar to this: https://ember-primitives.pages.dev/5-utils/proper-links

But potentially more directly / with less direction, you could add an eventListener in your application route:

```js
export default class ApplicationRoute extends Route {
  beforeModel() {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.elementClicked);

    registerDestructor(() => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', this.elementClicked);
    });

  }

  @action
  elementClicked(clickEvent) {
     // logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but what I desire is slightly different. Instead of defining the action separately for each component, I would like to define it globally in a single location. My intention is to trigger this globally defined action whenever any element within any component, which has the 'trackClick' attribute, is clicked.

Comment: thanks for the clarification -- I've added an example

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative of NullVoxPopuli's solution, instead of an attribute, you can [create a modifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-modifier) that adds and handles the click logic to the element is applied on, instead of listening to every click and checking if the element clicked is the one you want to do your logic.

Your template would end up looking like this:

```
// template.hbs
<div {{track-click "somevalue"}}>
  some text
</div>
```

And this is the modifier:

```js
// modifiers/track-click.js
import { modifier } from 'ember-modifier';

export default modifier((element, [ param ]) => {
  const handler = function () {
    // Your "onclick" logic
  };

  element.addEventListener('click', handler);

  return () => element.removeEventListener('click', handler);
});
```

The advantages of this approach is that you don't pollute the dom with attributes and you can pass more params or define flags for the `track-click` modifier without bloating the tag with more custom attributes. Quick examples: `{{track-click "somevalue" "othervalue"}}`, `{{track-click "somevalue" verbose=true}}`

---

*Out of scope:* You can even expand this idea and have a generic `track` modifier and use an attribute to define which event it tracks. Eg: `{{track "somevalue"}}` (event defaults to click), `{{track "somevalue" event="mouseenter"}}`

```
// template.hbs
<div {{track "clicked!"}} {{track "hovered!" event="mouseenter"}}>
  some text
</div>
```

```js
// modifiers/track.js
import { modifier } from 'ember-modifier';

export default modifier((element, [ param ], { event = 'click' }) => {
  const handler = function () {
    // Your "onclick" logic
  };

  element.addEventListener(event, handler);

  return () => element.removeEventListener(event, handler);
});
```